# Как удалить класс у других родителей при клике на дочерний?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При повторном клике не снимается активный класс .menu-catalog__open подскажите решение?

1. При клике на дочерний элемент с классом **.menu-catalog__link** родителю этого элемента с классом **.menu-catalog__item** добавляется активный класс **.menu-catalog__open**
2. При клике на другие дочерние элементы с классом **.menu-catalog__link** удаляется активный класс **.menu-catalog__open** у других родителей с классом **.menu-catalog__item**

```js
/*
1. При клике на дочерний элемент с классом .menu-catalog__link родителю этого элемента с классом .menu-catalog__item добавляется активный класс .menu-catalog__open
2. При клике на другие дочерние элементы с классом .menu-catalog__link удаляется активный класс .menu-catalog__open у других родителей с классом .menu-catalog__item.
*/

var menuCatalogOpen = 'menu-catalog__open';

$('.menu-catalog__link').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu-catalog__item').removeClass(menuCatalogOpen);
  $(this).parent().toggleClass(menuCatalogOpen);
});
```

```css
.menu-catalog__open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-catalog">
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Первый пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Второй пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Третий пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Четвертый пункт</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Не удаляется класс .menu-catalog__open при повторном клике!**

Comment: Юмор это хорошо, а вот был бы признателен за подсказку, как решать данную задачу.

Comment: В чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Не удаляется класс .menu-catalog__open при повторном клике

Comment: @alex-lenk удаляется, просто вы снова его добавляете

Comment: Я понимаю это, если закомментировать эту строку $('.menu-catalog__item').removeClass(menuCatalogOpen); то все работает как надо, однако, тогда активный класс добавляется и другим элементам!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var menuCatalogOpen = 'menu-catalog__open';

$('.menu-catalog__link').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass(menuCatalogOpen)) {
    $('.menu-catalog__item').removeClass(menuCatalogOpen);
  } else {
    $('.menu-catalog__item').removeClass(menuCatalogOpen);
    $(this).parent().addClass(menuCatalogOpen);
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-catalog__open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-catalog">
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Первый пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Второй пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Третий пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Четвертый пункт</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Artem Gorlachev, спасибо большое, добавил свое решение, подскажите, насколько оно хуже/лучше вашего, или быстрее/медленнее?

Answer (score 3):

В процессе поиска решения задачи, пришел к еще одному решению, хотел бы услышать мнение экспертов, хорошее ли это решение:

```js
var menuCatalogOpen = 'menu-catalog__open';

$('.menu-catalog__link').on('click', function() {
  var $item = $(this).parent();
  $('.menu-catalog__item').not($item).removeClass(menuCatalogOpen);
  $item.toggleClass(menuCatalogOpen);
});
```

```css
.menu-catalog__open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-catalog">
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Первый пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Второй пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Третий пункт</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-catalog__item">
    <div class="menu-catalog__link">Четвертый пункт</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, тоже про not хотел написать, оно как минимум изящнее. По скорости среди этих вариантов разницы существенной точно нет, а вот события лучше вешать выше – `$('.menu-catalog').on('click', '.menu-catalog__link', function(){});` – так будет одно событие на весь контейнер, а не на все блоки внутри